# "Driver not loaded" when trying connect to SQL Database in pyqt5 with python 3.7 (x64)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pyqt5

I try to convert an old pyqt4 program to pyqt5 and change to python x64.

When querying the db the first time, I get a **"Driver not loaded"** error.

When I use mysql.connector.connect I can get data from the db without any problems.

I tried the last four nights to solve this problem and at the moment, don´t know any further.

Things I tried:

- installed qt
- install 32 bit python
- download winpython which includes pyqt
- deinstall of all python on the system an reinstall
- installed mysql / and connector
- tryied anaconda

I believe one of my problems is, that print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()) only gives me: 
['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']

In the corresponding folder (as far as I understand) "C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\sqldrivers" are only the following three files:
qsqlite.dll,qsqlodbc.dll,qsqlpsql.dll

I downloaded the qsqlmysql.dll file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyqt/python-qt5/master/PyQt5/plugins/sqldrivers/ , After that "QMYSQL" and "QMYSQL3" are listed with print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()) , but with this file my python crashes hard.

What could I try next? What do I do wrong?

Database is "Server-Version: 5.5.57-MariaDB - MariaDB Server"

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic, QtSql

from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSql, QSqlDatabase, QSqlDriver,
    QSqlDriverCreatorBase, QSqlError, QSqlField, QSqlIndex, QSqlQuery,
    QSqlQueryModel, QSqlRecord, QSqlRelation, QSqlRelationalDelegate,
    QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlResult, QSqlTableModel)


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.db_connection = QSqlDatabase.database()
    print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())
    self.db_connection = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    self.db_connection.setHostName(db_sql_server_ip)
    self.db_connection.setDatabaseName(db_db_name)
    self.db_connection.setUserName(db_user)
    self.db_connection.setPassword(db_pw)
    self.db_connection.setPort(int(db_sql_server_port))
    self.db_connection.setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1")


    # first function which will get sql data
    query = QSqlQuery()

    # for demonstration
    self.setting_name='123'

    query.prepare("SELECT name,settings_value,pickled_data FROM settings WHERE user_id = ? AND active='1' AND name = ?")
    query.addBindValue(_user_id)
    query.addBindValue(self.setting_name)   

    query_status = query.exec_()
    if query_status is not True:
        errorText = query.lastError().text()
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Query error', errorText + str(57))
```

Code without qt can access sql:

```
    # the following works, but I need qt..
    import mysql.connector

    db = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_sql_server_ip,  # your host, usually localhost
                         user=db_user,  # your username
                         passwd=db_pw,  # your password
                         db=db_db_name)  # name of the data base

    # you must create a Cursor object. It will let
    #  you execute all the queries you need
    cur = db.cursor()

    # Use all the SQL you like
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

    # print all the first cell of all the rows
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        print(row[0])

    db.close()
```

Comment: System is Windows 10 / x64